# Change input value using NgModel object reference. Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a Angular form with **Template Driven Validation** implemented.

Eg:

```
<input name="username" #username="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="loginDetail.username">
```

Now, I need to access that input field in component, using **ViewChild**.

**COMPONENT**

```
@ViewChild('username') un;

ngOnInit() {
  console.warn(this.un.value);
}
```

Now, that prints the value of the input if any.
But, I have a need that, I need to reset the input value, if any particular value is present. Eg:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if(this.un.value == "username") {
    // Reset the input value to null
  }
}
```

But, I can't figure out how do I do that.

I tried:

```
if(this.un.value == "username") {
  this.un.value = null;    // <-- This does nothing
}
```

But, that is not working as it's not the correct way. Please help!

Comment: `un` should be a `FormControl` and you should try `this.un.setValue("xyz")`

Comment: *When* do you need to reset the value. And why would you need to have access to the NgModel or the DOM element to do that? You're using bidirectional binding, so just do `this.loginDetail.username = ''`.

Comment: @BillCheng I did `this.un.control.setValue(null)` and it worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: @JBNizet I totally agree, but I have a situation where I can't do that. Sorry, can't explain why.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
if(this.un.value == "username") {
  this.un.nativeElement.value = null;
}
```

Comment: `nativeElement` is available for template reference variable. But, `this.un` is a NgModel Object Reference